# How to form REST URL?

Tags: java, rest, http, jersey

I'm new to REST and i'm going through some of the examples. And confused with URL formation, Say i have two different use cases.

1) I want to display all the available products(in my store)

```
 /app/version1/products  - this would give all products 
 /app/version1/products/1  - this would give product with id 1
```

2) I want to display all the top rated products

Now my question is, will my URL looks like

```
 /app/version1/products/topratedProducts
```

or

```
  /app/version1/topratedproducts
```

Which URL is preferable ? why ?

Thanks

Comment: It should be /app/version1/products/topratedProducts which will give info of the module and service inside that module

Comment: I'd use `/app/version1/products/toprated` myself.

Answer (score 1):

```
/app/version1/products  - this would give all products 
/app/version1/products/1  - this would give product with id 1
```

Both these URL looks good and refers to resources.

When you explicitly want to go for `specifications` in the list of products, I would suggest to use `Query params`.

Example:

```
/app/version1/products{?type}
```

Sample URL:

```
/app/version1/products?type=TOP
/app/version1/products?type=AVERAGE
```

Where you maintain a type in Back end and support to get different type of products.

Going for different URL may increase consumption end point but ideally this is just a specification in all the products that are listed out.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer /app/version1/products/topratedProducts as you want to get toprated products from Product list , it is a good convention. if you closely look at the products routes all are following the same convention , for example you want to show one product which has id 1 then url will be app/version1/prodcuts/1 instead app/version1/1 (it does not make any sense) .

REST follows very good convenstion, I suggest you to closely look at routes when you did scaffold .